# AngularJS dynamic routing issue

Tags: angularjs, express

I am trying to display view by using dynamic routing. For this I am using ***":"***

notation. Once data comes back from the server, `$location.path('/postuser/'+permalink)` is used to redirect to the view. But for some reason  I am getting 404 error.

**I am using Html 5 mode. I think this the issue.**

`$location.path('/postuser/'+permalink)` sends request to the server:

> http://www.learntest/partials/userspostpage.html.

instead of this

> http://www.learntest/postuser/somedata.

**Here is the  router sample**

```javascript
test.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/welcome', {templateUrl: 'partials/welcome.html', controller: 'welcomeController'});

$routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', controller: 'singupController'});
$routeProvider.when('/signup', {templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html', controller: 'singupController'});
$routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'homeController'});
$routeProvider.when('/create', {templateUrl: 'partials/new.html', controller: 'CrudController'});
$routeProvider.when('/user/:permalink', {templateUrl: 'partials/userspostpage.html', controller: 'CrudController'});

$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```

}]);

```
 test.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

}]);

**AngularJS files and folder structure**

[image]

Also in back end I am using ExpressJS router

**ExpressJS router**

```
app.get("/postuser/:permalink", daataN);
```

if I remove `/:permalink` from the `$routeProvider` I am able to get the response. But I want url to be dynamic

Please let me know what is the issue here

Comment: I did not understood your comment, daataN is function which return json data

Comment: Are you using html5mode with angular?

Comment: Yes I am using html5mode

Comment: guys help me I struck

Answer (score 1):

My guess, since you say you're using html5mode is that the server is handling the route before the client gets a chance, thus you will always trigger the GET action on the server before the angular router has a chance to deal with the request.

I think you have a couple of options:

1. Choose a different server side controller name. (i.e. in express app.get('/user/:permalink'...))
2. Choose a different client side base route. (i.e. in router '/user/:permalink')
3. Completely diverge the two because it sounds like you are doing something bad when you have a server route and a client route that perfectly match. The client side routes should make sense for users to copy/paste or bookmark. The server side routes should make sense for you to use as an API. It seems unlikely that they would match.

Comment: exactly, Server is handling route before client get chance.

Comment: The key thing is that the ENTIRE route needs to change, just not the location of the wildcard definition. Your router needs to be something completely different i.e. '/user/:permalink' as opposed to '/postuser/:permalink'. See the difference?

Comment: changed the route  $location.path("/user/"+data.permalink). But I am getting  following error
GET http://localhost:3030/user/partials/userspostpage.html 404 (Not Found) angular.min.js:99
$get.id angular.min.js:99
n angular.min.js:95
l angular.min.js:94
$get.l.(anonymous function) angular.min.js:96
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:82
j.promise.then.h angular.min.js:78
j.promise.then.h angular.min.js:78
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:78
$get.e.$eval angular.min.js:88
$get.e.$digest angular.min.js:86
$get.e.$apply angular.min.js:88
e angular.min.js:95
p angular.min.js:98

Comment: Please update your original post with the current state of the router as well as the locations of your templates, etc.

Comment: I have added current state of router and location of templates